# convert inkpresenter signature to Base64 String

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, base64

My  requirement  is  need  to  capture  user  signature  with  InkPresenter...
then  inkpresenter  data  needs  to  be converted  to  base64 string ..

my  Inkpresenter  in xaml

```
<InkPresenter x:Name="inkSignature" Height="428" Width="450"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="MyIP_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                LostMouseCapture="MyIP_LostMouseCapture" 
                MouseMove="MyIP_MouseMove" 
                Background="White" Canvas.Top="53" Canvas.Left="3" Opacity="1"   >

            </InkPresenter>
```

on  clicking  the  Proceedbutton ..i  need  to  capture Inkpresenter  content  and  save to base64  string..

the  logic  i  have  implemented..

```
private void ProceedClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(inkSignature, new TranslateTransform());
        EditableImage eiImage = new EditableImage(wbBitmap.PixelWidth, wbBitmap.PixelHeight);

        try
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < wbBitmap.PixelHeight; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < wbBitmap.PixelWidth; ++x)
                {
                    int pixel = wbBitmap.Pixels[wbBitmap.PixelWidth * y + x];
                    eiImage.SetPixel(x, y,
                    (byte)((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF),
                    (byte)((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF),
                    (byte)(pixel & 0xFF), (byte)((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot print images from other domains");
        }

        // Save it isolated storage
        Stream streamPNG = eiImage.GetStream();
        StreamReader srPNG = new StreamReader(streamPNG);
        byte[] baBinaryData = new Byte[streamPNG.Length];
        long bytesRead = streamPNG.Read(baBinaryData, 0, (int)streamPNG.Length);

        //Obtain a virtual store for application
        IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(ClsCommon.signImage, FileMode.Create, fileStorage);
        isfStream.Write(baBinaryData, 0, baBinaryData.Length);
        isfStream.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Your signature has been saved. Thank you !", "mPOS", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        ConvImagetoBase64();
       // this.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }

    public void ConvImagetoBase64()
    {
        byte[] data;
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (store.FileExists(ClsCommon.signImage))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = store.OpenFile(ClsCommon.signImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {

                    // Allocate an array large enough for the entire file
                    data = new byte[isfs.Length];

                    // Read the entire file and then close it
                    isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    isfs.Close();
                }
                // Create memory stream and bitmap
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                byte[] bytearray = null;
                bytearray = ms.ToArray();
                string result= Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);

            }
        }
    }
```

while  debugging  at  String  result  value=
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////xkZ//8AAP//AAD//t/f/v/////////////////////////////////////+19f+/wUF//8AAP//AAD//qOj/v/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////vv7/v8AAP//AAD//wAA//77+/7//////////////////////////////////////0VF//8AAP//AAD//z09/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

A  lot  of  this..  finally  ending  with
/zOLXCCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

whats  the  mistake  iam  doing...please  guide  me  regrading  this..

if you have  any  other   easy approach please  suggest....

Comment: So, what exactly is not working?  `/` is a valid character in the [Base64 index table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples), so it's not obvious that anything is wrong.

Comment: the  output  i am  getting  is a  not  a  valid  one....it  should  be  some  thing  like          iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKoAAABBCAYAAABB9T/DAAAAAXNMIIg499+t8oXZ1Op33ql5ZKLqatfa6uTcnJ+ec7JzkDvWY/Otf/5r+H/cn/vnPfw4xkoV5/0byMOvfSBYW/TfSAYv+m/zjH/+Y3kuMAr0aRnruR4xsh5HsRmLU52oY6YGR7P2IyV//+tfpvcTf//73YYBmriCbNmCgnL///vvTN998c7p169Zqh/7ZFDhnmzr2uObomjbafvTRR9VPtrV9K7uuLBatfb9FTATsfoMA4YoUQyPrggw/WOuT8wx/+UK8j81NPPVVlkSRk1u7JJ5+cHjlyZIV8I8TYxJ9Gvj5s2b07fffnuFTBnAjUC9XXs2LE6gdk0ittvCZkQMPss+2FH9qgXXD7ZM79V/HjJF1QGsuhBHpmskqPEmLWKoE2lKNUCGcX7Vwg8MozrtuljI4hJUBL4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC